# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'className' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I'm trying to code an image slider into my website but I'm receiving this error whenever I try to debug:

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'className' of
>   undefined or null reference

When I use chrome to inspect the elements, it shows a null reference for the className property of the project# div tags, yet I defined the class for each of these tags in the html code. I'm so lost, I don't understand what's causing the detection error. Your help will be much appreciated. All the relevant code is below. Thank you :)

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tebello | Projects</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<div id="slider">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!--start slide 1 -->
        <div class="content" id="project1">
            <img src="images/NumScram.png" />
            <div class="text">
                <h3>Project name</h3>
                <p>A short description of the project</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <!-- end slide1 -->

        <!--start slide 2 -->
        <div class="content" id="project2">
            <img src="images/WebCalc.png" />
            <div class="text">
                <h3>Project name</h3>
                <p>A short description of the project</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <!--end slide2 -->

        <!--start slide 3 -->
        <div class="content" id="project3">
            <div class="text">
                <h3>Project name</h3>
                <p>A short description of the project</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
         <!--end slide3 -->
    </div>
    <!--end wrapper-->
</div>
<!--end slider-->

<!--Start navlinks-->
<div id="navlinks">
    <ul>
        <li class="itemlinks" data-pos="0px">1</li>
        <li class="itemlinks" data-pos="-823px">2</li>
        <li class="itemlinks" data-pos="-1646px">3</li>
        <li class="itemlinks" data-pos="-2469px"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--end navlinks-->
```

Javascript:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".itemlinks");
var wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.addEventListener('click', setPosition, false);
}

addClass(links[0], "active");

function setPosition(e) {
    removeActiveLinks();

    var clickedLink = e.target;
    addClass(clickedLink, "active");

    var position = clickedLink.getAttribute("data-pos");
    wrapper.style.left = position;
}

function removeActiveLinks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        removeClass(links[i], "active");
    }
}

function addClass(element, classToAdd) {
    var currentClassValue = element.className;

    if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToAdd) == -1) {
        if ((currentClassValue == null) || (currentClassValue === "")) {
            element.className = classToAdd;
        } else {
            element.className += " " + classToAdd;
        }
    }
}

function removeClass(element, classToRemove) {
    var currentClassValue = element.className;

    // removing a class value when there is more than one class value present
    // and the class you want to remove is not the first one
    if (currentClassValue.indexOf(" " + classToRemove) != -1) {
        element.className = element.className.replace(" " + classToRemove, "");
        return;
    }

    // removing the first class value when there is more than one class
    // value present
    if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToRemove + " ") != -1) {
        element.className = element.className.replace(classToRemove + " ", "");
        return;
    }

    // removing the first class value when there is only one class value 
    // present
    if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToRemove) != -1) {
        element.className = element.className.replace(classToRemove, "");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely your elements don't exist at the time the script is executed, unless you add an event on document ready, or load the script before the closing body tag.

Comment: It does not have to do with className, it has to do with the element not being there that you are trying to reference.

Comment: It's a very basic error of including your javascript in head instead of body.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with place where you added your `script.js` file. 
You are trying to include your javascript code in `head` tag. So the javascript code execute before the DOM has rendered and the element to which you are adding the `class` doesn't exists yet.

Include the script right before `</body>`.

```
<html>
<head>
...more html...
</head>
<body>
...more html...
...more html...

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested the code with correction and it works. I hope it helps.

Note: `body` tag is missing in code snippet you shared. I am assuming that is present in actual code.

Comment: Body tags are optional, so "missing" is fine and not required in actual code.

Answer (score 0):

In you case your JavaScript is executing before complete page loads and that's you your `document.querySelectorAll(".itemlinks");` code is returning `links` with zero length.
Solution to your question to use JavaScript code on load. (Please refer below code)

```
 window.onload = function(){
        var links = document.querySelectorAll(".itemlinks");
        var wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            var link = links[i];
            link.addEventListener('click', setPosition, false);
        }

        addClass(links[0], "active");

        function setPosition(e) {
            removeActiveLinks();

            var clickedLink = e.target;
            addClass(clickedLink, "active");

            var position = clickedLink.getAttribute("data-pos");
            wrapper.style.left = position;
        }

        function removeActiveLinks() {
            for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                removeClass(links[i], "active");
            }
        }

        function addClass(element, classToAdd) {
            var currentClassValue = element.className;

            if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToAdd) == -1) {
                if ((currentClassValue == null) || (currentClassValue === "")) {
                    element.className = classToAdd;
                } else {
                    element.className += " " + classToAdd;
                }
            }
        }

        function removeClass(element, classToRemove) {
            var currentClassValue = element.className;

            // removing a class value when there is more than one class value present
            // and the class you want to remove is not the first one
            if (currentClassValue.indexOf(" " + classToRemove) != -1) {
                element.className = element.className.replace(" " + classToRemove, "");
                return;
            }

            // removing the first class value when there is more than one class
            // value present
            if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToRemove + " ") != -1) {
                element.className = element.className.replace(classToRemove + " ", "");
                return;
            }

            // removing the first class value when there is only one class value
            // present
            if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToRemove) != -1) {
                element.className = element.className.replace(classToRemove, "");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please up vote it if this code works fine.